# How do I get a delay in motion to happen? (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation

I want the cockpits rotation to lag behind that of the cameras, so I wrote this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Delay : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform BodyRot;
    public Transform CurrentRot;
    public Vector3 changeInRot;
    public float divideRot;
    Vector3 BodyTarget;
    Vector3 CurrentInitialRot;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 BodyTarget = BodyRot.rotation.eulerAngles;

        Vector3 CurrentInitialRot = CurrentRot.rotation.eulerAngles;

        changeInRot = BodyTarget -= CurrentInitialRot;



        if(CurrentInitialRot != BodyTarget)
        {
            RotateFinal();
        }

    }

    void RotateFinal()
    {
        CurrentInitialRot += changeInRot / divideRot;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(CurrentInitialRot);
    }
}
```

But it glitches out frequently. (DivideRot is how many times to divide the distance between the target and current position, so that it takes time to rotate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t rely on `eulerAngles` for animating rotation. Use [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) instead. Your divideRot also does not take frame rate into account, which can cause jittery animation.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, BodyRot.rotation, someSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Where `someSpeed` is the speed you want to rotate in degrees per second. So try starting with 360 and adjust up or down from there.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! I did not even know this existed.....

Comment: Feel free to click the checkbox